# Android release build failing but debug version builds OK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-gradle-plugin, wear-os

I'm working on a small Android Wear OS app and am pretty close to a release version.

The app is built in Android Studio using the Wear OS application template and it currently has just the one Activity (`MainActivity`).

Up to now I have been building a `debug` variant without any problems. I didn't need to tweak anything to make that work.

But now I am trying to build a `release` variant I am getting the following error:

```
Error: MainActivity must extend android.app.Service [Instantiatable]
```

My `AndroidManifest.xml` is as follows and it's the `<service android:name="MainActivity"` that is flagging as the error in the editor with `MainActivity` underlined in red:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
        android:required="true" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
        android:value="true" />

    <!-- Recommended for Android 9 (API level 28) and lower. -->
    <!-- Required for Android 10 (API level 29) and higher. -->
    <service
        android:name="MainActivity"
        android:foregroundServiceType="location" >
    <!-- Any inner elements would go here. -->
    </service>


    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

My `MainActivity` currently extends `Activity`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

I have no idea how to resolve this... it doesn't make sense to me that the `debug` variant builds and runs fine but the `release` variant doesnt.

The only `release` build specific stuff in my `build.gradle` is:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

When I switch back to the `debug` variant the app build and runs perfectly on both an AVD Wear OS device and on an actual device.